# Avoid redundancy / reuse ModuleID in build.sbt and project/plugins.sbt?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I'd like to refer to the same version of a plugin in a `build.sbt` and in `project/plugins.sbt`. Both need to refer to e.g. `val sbtGit = "com.typesafe.sbt" %%   "sbt-git" % "1.0.0"`. 
Adding it to `project/Dependencies.scala` and importing does not work for `project/plugins.sbt`.

***Can I avoid the redundancy of specifying the sbt-git version twice?***

Answer (score 0):

A suggested solution in Sbt's Gitter is to [use a symlink](https://github.com/scalacenter/scastie/tree/master/project/project).